# java pointers, what is the difference between these 2 loops?

Tags: java, list, pointers, syntax

i am storing data in a simple linked list structure,
what is the difference between these 2 loops in java? i thought the first one would do the same as the second one with less code, but it doesn't work.

```
//1
temp = list.firstElement;
while (temp != null) {
  temp = temp.nextElement;
}
temp = *data*;

//2
if (list.firstElement == null) {
  list.firstElement = *data*;
}
else {
  temp = list.firstElement;
  while (temp.nextElement != null) {
    temp = temp.nextElement;
  }
  temp.nextElement = *data*;
}
```

why does the second one add something to the list, but the first doesn't? (first element is still null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first snippet, all `temp = data;` does is change what the `temp` variable refers to - it doesn't modify any of the objects in the list.

```
+--+  +--+  +--+  +--+             temp->+--+         
|  |->|  |->|  |->|  |->null             |  |
+--+  +--+  +--+  +--+             data->+--+
```

In the second snippet, when `temp` is something in your list, `temp.nextElement = data;` will assign `data` to something that is actually found in the list, thus modifying the list.

```
             temp---+
                    V 
+--+  +--+  +--+  +--+             
|  |->|  |->|  |->|  |-------->+--+   
+--+  +--+  +--+  +--+         |  |
                         data->+--+
```

Answer (score 1):

You drop out of the first loop exactly when temp==null, i.e. you completely dropped out of the list already.

You drop out of the second loop when temp.nextElement==null, which in particular means temp!=null. That again means temp is pointing to the last element of your list and you can successfully set its nextElement field.

Answer (score 1):

With the first loop you go though until the current element is null then you assign something to that value but no one is pointing to your new value, so it is not visible.

with the second loop you go through until your nextElement is null then you assign that so it will have someone pointing to it.